# C# class objects

Tags: c#, class, object

I have a class that I am using below. And I am using this class for my windows application. However, when I call the method from my application ReadInConfig() it successfully reads and fills the datatable, and assigns the _sip_ip address.

In my windows application I have the following. However, it doesn't give me the sip_ip that it has been assigned.

```
ConfigSIP readIn = new ConfigSIP();
readIn.ReadInConfig();
string sip_ip = readIn.sip_ip(); // Get nothing here.
```

I am thinking as the _sip_ip that has been assigned by the data table is a different object than doing this readIn.sip_ip();

Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Many thanks,

```
public class ConfigSIP
{
    private string _sip_ip;

        // Fill the data table and assign the sip ip.
    public void ReadInConfig()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Admin");
        dt.ReadXmlSchema(@"C:\Config.xml");
        dt.ReadXml(@"C:\Config.xml");

        _sip_ip = dt.Rows[0]["Sip_ip"].ToString();
    }

        // Return the sip ip address.
    public string sip_ip()
    {
        return _sip_ip;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "nothing"? An empty string? If so, this is a perfectly valid value for the _sip_ip field. If it is not a valid value, then put an assertion right after assigning it, which states so.

Comment: **NOTE** the OP edited the missing line into the question as it was being answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to call ReadInConfig:

```
ConfigSIP readIn = new ConfigSIP();
readIn.ReadInConfig();
string sip_ip = readIn.sip_ip();
```

Comment: Hello, sorry. I was calling ReadInConfig(). when I copied and pasted I must have left it out. I have now edited my code.

Comment: In that case my guess is that dt.Rows[0]["Sip_ip"].ToString() is empty. Try setting a breakpoint at that line and see what your datatable contains.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is copied verbatim your client code isn't calling the ReadInConfig() method. So the string will never get populated.